# Convergence of Arnoldi method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to compute the largest real eigenvalue of a matrix in the following form:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & I_n \\ P & Q \end{bmatrix},$$
where $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, $P$, $Q$ are symmetric real $n \times n$ matrices.

Now, I can't use power iteration, because there's no guarantee that I will have a unique largest magnitude eigenvalue; so I've been looking into the Arnoldi method.

However, none of the references I've seen have discussed when the Arnoldi method is guaranteed to converge.  Because of the nature of the motivating problem, I know that the largest magnitude eigenvalue(s) are real. So is the Arnoldi method guaranteed to converge for this case?

Comment: Experimentally, I'm noticing that Arnoldi displays an early breakdown behavior even with banded p.s.d. matrices. I haven't found sufficient convergence criteria in the literature I've used to implement my version.